# Shall I put the WHERE clause in or outside the subquery (derived table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm writing a query with 2 derived tables (or you may call them subqueries) and a WHERE clause for filter, but I don't know where should I place the WHERE clause to optimize the performance. Please see the example below:
(I definitely know this is a silly example, but it helps to describe my question)

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT id FROM A) A
    JOIN
    (SELECT id FROM B) B
    ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.id = 1
```

VS

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT id FROM A
     WHERE A.id = 1
    ) A
    JOIN
    (SELECT id FROM B
     WHERE B.id = 1
    ) B
    ON A.id = B.id
```

From the performance perspective, does it matter where I place the WHERE clause?
My database is too small, so I didn't see any difference when I tested the queries.
Thank you.

Comment: What's preventing you from doing SELECT * FROM A JOIN B on A.id = b.ID WHERE A.Id = 1?

Comment: Well for one that second is not even valid syntax

Comment: Corrected that for him.

Answer (score 1):

neither if can avoid it
there does not seem to be a specific need in that example that requires a derived
the more complex you make it seems like the query optimizer has more chances to not do the best thing

that is just a really insane query but

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A 
JOIN B 
      on A.id = B.ID 
     and A.id = 1
```

or

```
SELECT A.id FROM A where A.Id = 1 
intersection 
SELECT B.id FROM B where B.Id = 1
```

If you are going to do a derived then I would typically start with the where IN the derived. What can happen to you is that in complex queries the optimizer gets stupid and goes a bunch of loop joins. You may even end up materializing the sub to #temp if it gets stupid and does a bunch of loops.

Comment: Derived tables do not "kill indexes" - easy for you to test this yourself.

Comment: Thanks dude. I absolutely know this query is insane, but I'm just try to describe my question using this silly example. The real query I'm working on is much more complex and will bore everyone for sure. :)

Comment: I would typically start with the where IN the derived.  What can happen to you is that in complex queries the optimizer gets stupid on you and does a bunch of loop joins.  You may even end up materializing the sub to #temp if it get stupid and does a bunch of loops.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes I said that poorly

Answer (score 0):

Tested this - the top query has `where` clause outside the nested `select`, lower query has the `where` clause inside the nested select.  This test was done with 200k rows.  I suspect that the difference in performance is negligible.

[image]

Comment: Please share the script used to generate the execution plans. Queries, table definitions etc  I would expect to see no difference at all between the plans.

Comment: Used the exact queries he asked about, I thought that would be obvious.